# Go server empty response in Docker container

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I have a Go server which something like that. Router is Gorilla MUX

```
var port string
if port = os.Getenv("PORT"); port == "" {
    port = "3000"
}
srv := &http.Server{
    Handler:      router,
    Addr:         "localhost:" + port,
    WriteTimeout: 15 * time.Second,
    ReadTimeout:  15 * time.Second,
}
fmt.Println("Server is running on port " + port)
log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServe())
```

Dockerfile is

```
# Build Go Server
FROM golang:1.14 AS go-build
WORKDIR /app/server

COPY cmd/ ./cmd
COPY internal/ ./internal
COPY go.mod ./
COPY go.sum ./
RUN go build ./cmd/main.go


CMD ["./main"]
```

I got successful a build. I ran it with following command

```
docker run -p 3000:3000 baaf0159d0cd
```

And I got following output. Server is running

```
Server is running on port 3000
```

But when I tried to send request with curl I got empty response

```
>curl localhost:3000
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Why is server not responding properly? I have another routes which I did not put here and they are not responding correctly too. I am on MacOS by the way.

Comment: It did not work.  `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 3000: Connection refused`

Comment: I think it is getting solved, thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use `localhost` (basically an alias to `127.0.0.1`) as your server address within a Docker container. If you do this only 'localhost' (i.e. any service within the Docker container's network) can reach it.

Drop the hostname to ensure it can be accessed outside the container:

```
// Addr:         "localhost:" + port, // unreachable outside container
Addr:         ":" + port, // i.e. ":3000" - is accessible outside the container
```

Comment: I made it. Now how am I going to test it? curl gives empty response still

Comment: Sure you restarted the container with `-p 3000:3000`?

Comment: It worked, thanks. I want to ask one more thing. I am working on a project and I this is a part of it. I need to write a Dockerfile and is the Dockerfile I wrote above correct? Does it work for production?

Comment: @TheExile here's a good resource on how to build a [minimal golang docker image](https://medium.com/@chemidy/create-the-smallest-and-secured-golang-docker-image-based-on-scratch-4752223b7324).

Comment: Can confirm that dropping 'localhost' from the full URL and just using `router.Run(":8000")` solved it for me. Thank you!