# docker-compose secrets MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE work correctly but DB_PASSWORD result empty string

Tags: mysql, docker, go, docker-compose, production-environment

## MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE work correctly but DB_PASSWORD result empty string

In my project. I use react as frontend, golang with fiber framework as backend and mysql as database.

It work fine when I set ENV in Dockerfile. but when I work with docker-compose secrets. In database container work correctly but in backend container. The environment variable result empty string,

## dockercompose.yml

```
version: '2.17.3'
  backend:
    container_name: app-backend
    image: app-backend:private
    build: 
      context: ./server/.
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.private
    secrets:
      - db_password
      - db_name
      - jwt_secret_key
      - mailer_password
      - mailer_username
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=my-database
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_USER=root
      - DB_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_password
      - DB_NAME_FILE=/run/secrets/db_name

      # Leave SERVER_HOST BLANK. Info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61047889
      - SERVER_HOST=
      - SERVER_PORT=8080
      - WEBSITE_HOST=localhost:3000

      - JWT_SECRET_KEY_FILE=/run/secrets/jwt_secret_key

      - MAILER_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
      - MAILER_PORT=587
      - MAILER_USERNAME_FILE=/run/secrets/mailer_username
      - MAILER_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/mailer_password

      - ALLOW_ORIGINS=http://localhost:3000
    
    ports:
      - 8000:8080
    user: nonroot:nonroot
    networks:
      - my-network

  database:
    container_name: app-database
    image: mysql
    build:
      dockerfile: ./server/Dockerfile.database
    secrets:
      - db_root_password
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_root_password
    ports:
      - 3307:3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - my-network
   
networks:
  my-network:

secrets:
  db_root_password:
    file: ./secrets/db_root_password.txt
  db_password:
    file: ./secrets/db_password.txt
  db_name:
    file: ./secrets/db_name.txt
  jwt_secret_key: 
    file: ./secrets/jwt_secret_key.txt
  mailer_password:
    file: ./secrets/mailer_password.txt
  mailer_username:
    file: ./secrets/mailer_username.txt
```

## Dockerfile.private

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1

##
## Build the application from source
##

FROM golang:1.20.4-bullseye AS build-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod go.sum ./
RUN go mod download && go mod verify

COPY . ./

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o main main.go

##
## Deploy the application binary into a lean image
##

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11 AS build-release-stage

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=build-stage /app/main .

EXPOSE 8080

USER nonroot:nonroot

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main"]
```

## Dockerfile.database

```
# database
FROM mysql

EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
```

## build script

`docker-compose up -d --build`

I've check `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_root_password` in mysql database. It work correctly. I can connect to database. but in backend. In docker-desktop logs show it have empty string

```
 ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────┐ 
 │                   Fiber v2.45.0                   │ 
 │               http://127.0.0.1:8080               │ 
 │       (bound on host 0.0.0.0 and port 8080)       │ 
 │                                                   │ 
 │ Handlers ............ 49  Processes ........... 1 │ 
 │ Prefork ....... Disabled  PID ................. 1 │ 
 └───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘ 
2023/05/22 22:21:30 Try connecting to database: %w root:@tcp(nf-theater-database:3306)/?parseTime=true
```

Here my golang connection code

```
package database

import (
    "database/sql"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func Connect() *sql.DB {
    dbUser := os.Getenv("DB_USER")
    dbPassword := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
    dbHost := os.Getenv("DB_HOST")
    dbPort := os.Getenv("DB_PORT")
    dbName := os.Getenv("DB_NAME")

    connString := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%s)/%s?parseTime=true", dbUser, dbPassword, dbHost, dbPort, dbName)
    log.Println("Try connecting to database: %w", connString)
    // Open database connection
    db, err := sql.Open("mysql", connString)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    }

    return db
}
```

I've try to change version in first line of docker-compose from version: '2.17.3' to version: '3.8' but result was the same

I don't understand why it's don't work. I don't want to switch to swarm if it don't have to. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MYSQL [`docker-entrypoint.sh`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L28) checks for the environment variable [`MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE`](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/master/8.0/docker-entrypoint.sh#L255) and, if present, loads the contents of the file named in the variable into the environmental variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` (which is then used elsewhere in the script as the password).

So there is no special handling of variables ending with `_FILE`; something in the container needs to check for the variable and load the data from the file.

Your `docker-compose.yml` sets the variable `DB_PASSWORD_FILE` and runs your application directly (`ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main"]`). You then attempt to read `DB_PASSWORD` (`dbPassword := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD")`); this will be empty because you have not set that environmental variable.

You could add a script, similar to that used in the MYSQL container, or just read the variable as set e.g.

```
dbPasswordFile := os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD_FILE")
dbPassword, err := os.ReadFile(dbPasswordFile)
```

*Note: You should probably check for a blank variable and handle any errors*